# jquery delegate same function to multiple elements

Tags: delegates

Maybe this is is a stupid question, but I'm more a webdesigner than a webdeveloper.

I've got 2 nav tags

```
  <nav id="navMenu" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="navMenuUL" class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href>...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

and

```
  <nav id="navSubMenu" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="navSubMenuUL" class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href>...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I want to delegate the same function to the "a" tags in both nav's

I tried

```
$("#navMenu, #navSubMenu").delegate("a", "click", function() {
 ....        
});
```

and

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
 ....        
});
```

but none of them worked.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both should work, try to check with debugger or console.log/alert. However, `delegate` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7. Use `on` instead. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SCdVD/ all three methods work.

Comment: I'll check the fiddle. thanks :-)

Comment: Tommi, it works; 
but now I'm trying to detect the href attribute of the "a" tag clicked, but it only returns the attr of the "a" tag of the first nav?!?!

Comment: Show your code then. `this` in callback will always be clicked element.

Comment: $("nav").on("click", "a", function() {
        _link = $(this).attr("href");
 //alert(_link)
        loadContent(_link);
        return false;
}

Comment: 1) Use `prop` instead `attr`; 2) `_link` should not be global, define it with `var` keyword. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SCdVD/1/

Comment: `("#navMenu a, #navSubMenu a").on('click',function(){ var link = $(this).attr("href"); });`

Comment: It only works for "#navMenu"! 
but I found what is going wrong with my case: it's because the "#navSubMenu" its a secondary nav that belongs to the content that it's loaded, via load(...), to a div in the page!
Is there any way to do this?